# Tool to create inscribed polygon from circular polygon in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, polygon-creation

I have created a circular polygon feature class after applying buffer tool in a point feature class (dissolve option activated).
Is there a tool that automatically creates an inscribed polygon inside the buffer circular polygon so to avoid creating it point by point like in the circle with the arrow in the image below?

[image]

Comment: If you have the points  and a distance, you can just do the math to create the polygons yourself, without the buffer. You just need to locate the points less than 2 x radius away to know where the line between them should be constructed. It's just a little trigonometry.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem is that I have a big number of points (more than 300), around of which I want to create these polygons of a max. distance. Is there a tool to create all of these polygons directly?

Comment: None that I know of, but you could write one in a few hours (or days).  BTW: 300 features would process in under a minute.

Comment: If I was capable to write such a tool, I wouldn't make this question

Comment: Python is the world's easiest language to learn. You are capable of writing such a tool, or at least of starting one before asking for more input.

Comment: I think it's time to get into Python's world. Thank you for your message

Comment: All you need is a buffer (which ArcPy provides) and the selection of nearby points (ditto) and the calculation of a midpoint (high school math), and construction of a line between the two points (ArcPy again), with which you could cut the circle (and again).  Repeat for all nearby points, then repeat for each successive point. Bonus points for caching the constructed line, since you'll need it again for clipping the paired circle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141223/discussion-between-cartographer67-and-vince).

Answer (score 1):

I would abandon using the buffer tool and use the Euclidean Allocation tool (@FelixIP hints at this).

The trick is to set the maximum distance, the points in my example are 500m apart along a river, but I set the maximum distance to be 300m to create the overlap, also set cell size to be something quite small, in my example 1m is sufficient.

[image: Euclidean allocation]

Then its a matter of converting to polygon:

[image: Polygons]

Comment: +1 nice, but point 44 is a problem.

Comment: I understood the OP question to be asking for what I have shown in my answer. But you highlighting 44 made me think I missed something and I did (not being a mathematician by training) I had not realised that _inscribed_ is a geometric property as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_figure). But their dark polygon is not an inscribed polygon it shows a bisecting edge. I think OP needs to clarify what they are asking for.  Interesting problem though.

Answer (score 0):

See if this will work. Do not dissolve circles. Simplify them playing with different Simplification Tolerance until you are happy with what you call inscRibed polygon.

[image]

Dissolve outputs into single part shapes:

[image]

Comment: I think the OP also wants the bisector line between the buffers, so the full circle where exclusive, with the overlap evenly divided (without hand-drawing).

Comment: Yes @Vince you are correct, I've missed it. I'd do it using Cost allocation to center points.